# Which directory is best for this wallpaper package?

Tags: lyx

I'm new to Lyx, and I'm trying to install this wallpaper package(http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/).

Here's the installation instructions:

> Installation of the package only concerns unpacking the archive in a directory of your choice. Its most convenient to unpack the archive in a directory included in the TEXINPUTS environment
>   variable (at our institute, in your .TeX directory in your home directory). Unpacking is done using
>   the command:
>   tar -xzf wallpaper.tgz

Unfortunately, I don't understand what directories I'm supposed to download the package into, let alone which directories are included in the TEXINPUTS environment. Where should I download the package to?

Also, where would I place the unpacking command? In the Latex Preamble?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: wallpaper is in texlive and miktex so you should almost never have to get it from ctan and install "by hand", have you tried just using the texlive or miktex package manager?

Answer (score 3):

`wallpaper.sty` goes into your LYX document's folder (wherever you save your LyX file is what LyX sets TEXINPUTS to), and you invoke it in `LyX>Document>Settings>Preamble` with `\usepackage{wallpaper}`.

Since it's on CTAN, the style can probably be installed system wide through your LaTeX package manager, in which case you can skip the first part. The package manager will download wallpaper.sty itself. On Fedora Linux, for example, you install it with `dnf install texlive-wallpaper`. 
The commands the package provides (check the manual) will have to be used through the LaTeX inset in LyX (Ctrl-L). If paths to background images are involved, you might need to use the absolute paths (`C:\Documents\whatever\image.png` or `/home/user/Documents/whatever/image.png`) so that LaTeX can find them from LyX' temporary compilation folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a few questions regarding it. When you say I can place the .sty file in the documents folder, do you mean just the default 'Documents' folder under 'My PC'?  Also, if I were to use package manager to install it(have it open now) where would I place the file so that it shows up in Package Manager?

Comment: I updated the answer. Save the wallpaper.sty wherever you saved your document.lyx.  Or... search for the wallpaper package on the list of the packages provided by the package manager, and let it download and install the package itself. If things don't work, please read the manual, as there are a few other packages that need to be installed alongside wallpaper.sty.